# Creating graphs in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graph

I'm creating a smartphone-game which measures the players reaction time. I would like to display a diagram showing their time for each click, as well as a line going through showing the average.

Image where I would like to put the diagram:

[image]

Is this something that can be achieved using Unity, or should I go to another software to get this done?

My reaction time variable is stored in an Array.

Comment: http://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/interfaces

Comment: Unity is indeed NOT IDEAL for drawing things like graphs or indeed lines.  The package Vectrosity is used by pretty much every developer, so get that.  But it is still a chore.  The simple answer is there is NO really good way to do this in Unity.  Its' a nuisance.

Comment: @JoeBlow So i've been messing around a bit, as my graph is gonna be rather simple, wouldn't it be effecient to just create an UI panel and scale it depending on my reactionTime variable?

Comment: yes, I suggest you make  "bar graph".  you can do that perfectly with Unity's excellent UI system.

Answer (score 4):

So, I'm sorry for necro-post but I was trying to get something like this done for a project and came up with this (below) to draw an sort of oscilloscope graph. I thought I'd post the very basics. It draws a graph in a moveable GUI.Window. There are no 'bells and whistles' at the moment. it just draws a load of random values but could be used as a start point for someone else.

```
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using UnityEngine;

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws a basic oscilloscope type graph in a GUI.Window()
        /// Michael Hutton May 2020
        /// This is just a basic 'as is' do as you wish...
        /// Let me know if you use it as I'd be interested if people find it useful.
        /// I'm going to keep experimenting wih the GL calls...eg GL.LINES etc 
        /// </summary>
        public class Graph : MonoBehaviour
        {

            Material mat;
            private Rect windowRect = new Rect(20, 20, 512, 256);

            // A list of random values to draw
            private List<float> values;

            // The list the drawing function uses...
            private List<float> drawValues = new List<float>();

            // List of Windows
            private bool showWindow0 = false;

            // Start is called before the first frame update
            void Start()
            {
                mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored"));
                // Should check for material but I'll leave that to you..

                // Fill a list with ten random values
                values = new List<float>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    values.Add(Random.value * 200);
                }
            }

            // Update is called once per frame
            void Update()
            {
                // Keep adding values
                values.Add(Random.value * 200);
            }

            private void OnGUI()
            {
                // Create a GUI.toggle to show graph window
                showWindow0 = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), showWindow0, "Show Graph");

                if (showWindow0)
                {
                    // Set out drawValue list equal to the values list 
                    drawValues = values;
                    windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, DrawGraph, "");
                }

            }


            void DrawGraph(int windowID)
            {
                // Make Window Draggable
                GUI.DragWindow(new Rect(0, 0, 10000, 10000));

                // Draw the graph in the repaint cycle
                if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
                {
                    GL.PushMatrix();

                    GL.Clear(true, false, Color.black);
                    mat.SetPass(0);

                    // Draw a black back ground Quad 
                    GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
                    GL.Color(Color.black);
                    GL.Vertex3(4, 4, 0);
                    GL.Vertex3(windowRect.width - 4, 4, 0);
                    GL.Vertex3(windowRect.width - 4, windowRect.height - 4, 0);
                    GL.Vertex3(4, windowRect.height - 4, 0);
                    GL.End();

                    // Draw the lines of the graph
                    GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
                    GL.Color(Color.green);

                    int valueIndex = drawValues.Count - 1;
                    for (int i = (int)windowRect.width - 4; i > 3; i--)
                    {
                        float y1 = 0;
                        float y2 = 0;
                        if (valueIndex > 0)
                        {
                            y2 = drawValues[valueIndex];
                            y1 = drawValues[valueIndex - 1];
                        }
                        GL.Vertex3(i, windowRect.height - 4 - y2, 0);
                        GL.Vertex3((i - 1), windowRect.height - 4 - y1, 0);
                        valueIndex -= 1;
                    }
                    GL.End();

                    GL.PopMatrix();
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope it's useful (probably not to the OP but...)

Michael

Comment: This saved me a ton of time today. Thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pym6m.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You can use some options to make lines in Unity.

1: [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html): very uggly and hard to got complex result

2: Pay for [Vectrosity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/vectrosity-82): More complex and suitable plugin.

3: Make your own diagram with planes and some code. I have a WIP plugin doing this method and i got very nices result. I can help you on this if have any question about this.

[image]

Comment: LIneRenderer is utterly wrong for this.  It just has no connection to it.

Comment: with LineRendere you can render a line using vector3 points. Why you tell is wrong?

Comment: it's for making a **3D**, lit and rendered, object.  you might as well try and make typography using cubes.  As you said, everyone uses Vectrosity.  But there's no good solution

Comment: LineRenderer make a line in 3d coord. Is a way to make a 2D or 3D graphs. Its not a good tool but is a posibility acording to the question. Not for typografy but yes for lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard Unity objects (with a Transform component), I think that the LineRenderer component could suit your need.

If you are using Unity UI (and need a component with a RectTransform), you can have a look here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/new-ui-and-line-drawing.253772/

Look at the post from jonbro5556, he apparently created a line component for Unity UI (I haven't tested it but it could be worth having a look)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Dynamic Line Chart - the plugin which is available in asset store

[Dynamic Line Chart](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/dynamic-line-chart-108651)

Or

You can try the following github repository which is able to draw line graphs.

[Line Graph](https://github.com/codemaker2015/line-graph)

You need to change the following lines from LineGraphManager script for live feed

```
void Start(){

        // adding random data
        int index = 120;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            GraphData gd = new GraphData();
            gd.marbles = Random.Range(10,47); // insert your data instead of random one
            graphDataPlayer1.Add(gd);
        }

        // showing graph
        ShowGraph();
    }
```